Countable complement extension topology; union of open sets
[From 'Counterexamples in Topology']1
Given $\cup_{\alpha \in \Lambda}(U_\alpha-C_\alpha)$, where $U_\alpha$ is an usual open set and $C_\alpha$ a countable set, I'd like to show that it's still an open set. I considered $(B_n)_n$ a countable basis of the usual topology on $X$ and
$$\cup_{\alpha \in \Lambda}(U_\alpha-C_\alpha)={\cup}_{j \in J \subset \mathbb{N}}(B_j - C'_j)$$
where $C'j$ is the intersection of all $C_\alpha$ such that $B_j \subset U_\alpha$. But I couldn't find a way to split it into$({\cup}_{j \in J \subset \mathbb{N}}B_j)-C $ with $C$ countable. Any suggestions?
EDIT:$${\cup}_{j \in J \subset \mathbb{N}}(B_j - C'_j)\subseteq {\cup}_{j \in J \subset \mathbb{N}}B_j;
$$
$${\cup}_{j \in J \subset \mathbb{N}}B_j \ - \ {\cup}_{j \in J \subset \mathbb{N}}(B_j - C'_j) \subseteq {\cup}_{j \in J \subset \mathbb{N}}(B_j-(B_j-C_j'))= {\cup}_{j \in J \subset \mathbb{N}} C'j \quad (\ast)$$
So, $${\cup}_{j \in J \subset \mathbb{N}}(B_j - C'_j)={\cup}_{j \in J \subset \mathbb{N}}B_j \ -  A$$ where $A$ is countable by $(\ast)$
Is this correct?
